# How to get a person’s username by his ID without a request to the graph?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How to get a person’s username by his ID without a request to the graph, or how to do this in the graph (as far as I have tried and know, such information is blocked for receipt)?

I'm trying to get data using the graph API method, but most of it, as I understand it, is blocked even for developers. Is it possible to somehow obtain username data from a person’s ID so that further work can be done, at least with scraping?

Comment: You do not get the username for a user profile any more via API, that possibility has been removed a long time ago.